# How to get combobox and radio button ''out of focus''?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2007

I'm trying to make an app which reads keys from the keyboard. When I press a key, the program adds it to an array and then I do what I want. I'm not writing in an Edit control. I'm directly pressing buttons on the keyboard, since I want to be able to work with other inputs like readers, that simulate input like keyboards.

Now I added a combo box and radio buttons, with which I'm going to add new stuff in the future. I tried the app again after I added the components and the program doesn't read the keys anymore, since it tries to write inside the combo box. If I press outside of the combo box, or choose an option, nothing happens, and it keeps trying to write in it.

If I press the radio button, the program no longer tries to write in the combo box, but it still doesn't read keys from the keyboard, probably because the focus now is on the radio button.

If I make the combo box property `Enabled := false` and I don't press a radio button, then it works again.

I think that the problem is that the program has it's 'focus' on the components. I looked into the properties of the components, and I don't see any property that could help.

Is there a way with code or a property on the components to make the components not take the focus of the program? I work with `TRadioButton`, `TComboBox` or `TAdvComboBox`.

I use the `FormKeyDown` event to get the key information.

procedure

```
TfrmConfigCheck.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
     
end;
```

Comment: Can you show your current code of what you've written to capture the key presses please?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt I use the FormKeyDown event. I don't see how that's relevant to my question, since my problem is with the components, which is why I didn't add the code the first time.

Comment: It is relevant, because now I understand how you're trying to do it. I think your problem is that the `KeyPreview` property on the form is disabled. If you make `KeyPreview` true, does that fix your issue?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt It does help a lot but doesn't completely fix my problem. If I choose option from the combo box and the press a radio button I can do it, but if I don't choose options from the radio button it still stays focused on the combo box. Is there a way to make the combo box readonly or something like that? Doesn't seem to have property of that name.

Comment: You can't make it `readonly`, but you can change the `style` property on the `TComboBox` to be `csDropDownList` and that's kind of `readonly` because a user can't enter his/her own text into it. Does that fix your other issue?

Comment: @ShaunRoselt Thank you very much. The 2 changes fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property on the form to `True`.

If `KeyPreview` is set to `False`, then the form's `onKeyDown` event isn't called when some components such as a `TComboBox` have focus.

But if you set the `KeyPreview` property to `True`, then the form's `onKeyDown` event is called every time a key is pressed down no matter what component is focused on the form.

---

And regarding your other issue in the comments, you can't set the `TComboBox` to be `readonly`, but you can set the `style` property to `csDropDownList` which is kind of a `readonly` mode since a user can't enter any detai

Comment: You should also add that in order to prevent key presses from propagating to currently focused control you should call `Key := #0;` from within forms `OnKeyPress` event since this tells application that current key press has already been handled.

Answer (score -1):

Under your application form event `TForm.OnShow` put `Form1.SetFocus`;
You can always do this under `onClick`, `onEnter`, etc of any control to return the focus to the form.